# x86-64 MOV r/m64, imm32 = io?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel

In the final form of MOV in the Intel x86 Software Develops manual (Vol 2A, 3-502 MOV--Move) it says:

```
Opcode               Instruction
REX.W + C7 /0 io     MOV r/m64, imm32
              ^^                ^^^^^
```

`io` signifies an 8 byte immediate.

Yet the parameter is denoted imm32 ?

The description is "Move imm32 sign extended to 64-bits to r/m64."

So it looks to me that `io` is a typo, and it should be `id`.

Is this a defect in the Intel manual, or am I missing something?

Is there a better place to report possible defects/errata in the Intel manual?

Comment: Is this the latest version on the website? my copy doesn't have this, just REX.W + C7 /0

Comment: @Leeor: Order Number: 253665-048US September 2013.  What does it say on the first page of your Volume 1?

Comment: Ok, mine is way older (2005, guess it's time to update), yours is the most recent one - http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf

Comment: @Leeor: So your copy has no io or id suffix at all on the opcode?  If so I guess older versions didn't include that it the doc then.

Comment: Looks like a defect to me. That wouldn't be surprising, Intel's manuals are always full of little mistakes like that.

Comment: Mine is Aug 2012, no sign of "io".  An 8 byte immediate is ib not io.  The /o looks a lot like io if not carefully read.  If it isn't your eyes betraying you then it was an Intel manual editor's probably.

Comment: @HansPassant `io` is indeed 8 byte (64 bit), `ib` is a single byte (8 bit). I agree it's a typo and should be `id`.

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed now: all the imm32 forms say `id`, in the latest version that http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html is extracted from.

I think you can report errors in manuals somewhere on Intel's forums.